# 2d Tile Map in javascript only showing a portion

Tags: javascript

I am using a 2d tilemap and when i try to render it in the canvas it comes out skewed
it is supposed to have a border around the canvas but instead i get a couple of rectengular tiles in the top left corner of the canvas
[The image of the full canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z07lV.png)

here is my code

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="c" style="border:3px solid black;"></canvas>
  <script>
    var c = document.getElementById("c");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var tilesize = 50;
    c.style.width = (10 * tilesize) + "px";
    c.style.height = (10 * tilesize) + "px";
    var w = c.width;
    var h = c.height;

    var cols = 10;
    var rows = 10;
    var map = [
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ]


    function drawmap() {
      for(var y = 0; y < map.length; ++y) {
        for(var x = 0; x < map[y].length; ++x) {
          if(map[y][x] == 1){
            ctx.fillRect(x*tilesize,y*tilesize,tilesize,tilesize)
          }
        }
      }

    }

    setInterval(update,10);
    function update(){
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
      drawmap()
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give the canvas the width and height in the expected number of pixels, you should set the `width` and `height` attributes. When you set the style, you don't actually change the coordinate system, but just stretch the canvas: the number of visible units does not change by it.

So change:

```
c.style.width = (10 * tilesize) + "px";
c.style.height = (10 * tilesize) + "px";
```

to:

```
c.width = 10 * tilesize;
c.height = 10 * tilesize;
```